# WCF Streaming Big file

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

How can I send the service a ref of a big file on the cliet's computer by a stream object and then start download piece by piece it from the client's computer (I decide how much MB I transfer every sec)? Do I have any limitations when I use it?

Comment: Are you hosting your WCF service in IIS?

Comment: Yes. Do you need any more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS doesn't support streaming - it buffers the whole request.

[CodeProject article: WCF 4.5 fixes this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/324010/What-s-new-in-WCF-4-5-Improved-streaming-in-IIS-ho)

Until then, if you use IIS, the whole file will be stored in server memory before it is passed to your service.

The solution for now is to send the file in chunks - each chunk sent in a separate service call.

This would also help with your bandwidth throttling. This is not built into WCF - you have to do it yourself. You can throttle each chunk either on the client or on the server.

Comment: How do I join them back ? I mean , Pack number 2 can come befor pack number 1, so how do i join them?

Comment: I would implement a simple protocol: add an `int index` and send it with each chunk. The client should serialize service calls anyway, though, so there is only one call in progress at a time.

Comment: you mean to send a message insted of stream so I can add the index to my transfare OR send it in for/while ?

Comment: Yes, send a normal message because streaming doesn't work in IIS. The message can contain an index integer along with the chunk as a byte[].